# Using Arrays For Function Input Argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to use an array for function's input argument, when I call this function with a manual value, the function works good, but when I use an array with that value instead of the manual value, my function doesn't work correctly.

Example of my code:

```
Search("FileName","Word");
----------------------
Search("NotePad1","Hello"); >>> Work Correctly!
----------------------
But:
--------------------

char Word[25]={'H','e','l','l','o'};

Search("NotePad1",Word); >>>Doesn't Work! :-(
--------------------
```

Comment: try `char Word[25]={'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};`

Comment: having a function declaration may be useful to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals such as `"Hello"` also include the NUL terminator byte at the end.

Add the terminator to your array as well:

```
char Word[25]={'H','e','l','l','o', 0};
```

Otherwise the C string read from the array will also contains any junk data at the end of the array and memory locations after it, up to the next zero byte in memory.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
char* Word = "Hello";
```

depends on how you declared your function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function declaration to be as

```
boolean Search(String Filename ,String word);
```

try

```
char Word[]={'H','e','l','l','o','\0'}; // <- NULL terminated , a well formed string
Search("NotePad1" , Word);
```

It is because `String` in C/C++ and null terminated.

**Conclusion** :

If you are passing char array where argument expects a String make sure the char array is null terminated or pass string as "this".